# Homebrew mongodb connection failed - Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I've installed mongodb with brew on my Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.6:

```
brew install mongodb
```

I get no errors when running:

```
brew services start mongodb
```

but when i try to run:

```
mongo
```

I get the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-02-05T14:55:25.952-0500 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-02-05T14:55:25.952-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I've removed the .plist files, made sure that /data/db is there and all necessary permissions are on it. I can start `mongodb` without a problem and everything runs but I cannot get it to run with `brew services start mongodb`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, it turns out that mongod service is not running, even though `brew services start mongodb` reports no problem.

But if run `mongod` directly, the service boots successfully. So the problem lies with the old database files in `/usr/local/var/mongodb`

(These config can be found in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist` and `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`)

In `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` I see a line says

> 2018-02-12T15:51:56.110+0800 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.

Then I installed mongodb 3.4 (`brew uninstall mongodb` `brew install mongodb@3.4`),

run 
`db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )` 
in mongo@3.4 shell,

stop the mongodb service (`brew services stop mongodb@3.4`),

upgrade mongodb again to 3.6 (`brew uninstall mongodb@3.4` `brew install mongodb`),

problem solved.

(rm /usr/local/var/mongodb/*.lock if needed)

Comment: how do you get the mongo@3.4 shell? :o

Comment: ah okay you need to brew link --force mongodb@3.4 and then the mongo alias works

Comment: and, I didn't try running brew services install mongodb but it should just be brew install mongodb right? In your answer

Answer (score 25):

If you don't need to keep your current data:

`brew services stop mongodb`

`brew uninstall mongodb`

`rm -rf /usr/local/var/mongodb/`

`rm -rf ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist`

`rm -rf /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

`brew install mongodb`

`brew services start mongodb`

should upgrade to the newest version and start it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one works for me! Also may be helpful to run ```brew link --overwrite mongodb``` after all this operations.

Comment: Emmm, it seems that "/usr/local/var/mongodb/" contains an older version of data files, it should be deleted

Comment: This was a huge help, Thanks!

Comment: In my case @gorjanz, as i was installing in a new user space, i needed to configure the user in the permission group of the `/usr/` folder and also had to give read and write permission to the user for that folder, like brew recommended.
After that, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Same appended to me. After running `brew services start mongodb-community@4.2`, brew didn't throw any error, but there was actually one. I looked into the MongoDB log file (`/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`) and I found the error:

```
IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

Starting MongoDB with brew makes it start as you, so you must have the rights to write in the data folder, which is located under `/usr/local/var/mongodb`.

In order to make sure you have the rights to write in this folder, navigate to the parent folder:

```
cd /usr/local/var
```

and run

```
sudo chown -R $USER mongodb
```

which will make you the owner of the folder and all files within this folder.

Stop MongoDB, restart it, and it should work:

```
brew services stop mongodb-community@4.2

brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
```